# Differences between two ways to position elements in BorderPane?

Tags: java, javafx

Code example:

```java
Label label = new Label("Random text");
BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();

layout.topProperty().set(label); //1st way
layout.setTop(label); //2nd way
```

What is the exact difference between these two ways of setting *top* property in `BorderPane` layout mode?

Comment: there is no difference.

Comment: Look at the source code for `BorderPane`. Method `setTop` calls `topProperty().set`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107

Comment: setTop() is a delegate to topProperty().set()